# How to manage environment specific files in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am having properties file specific for dev, test and other environments. I have to store this files in some secure place in aws. I am using AWS Native tools for build and deployment. Please let me know how to store these files in aws

Comment: where you will consume these secret?like service ECS, ec2 lamda?

Comment: right now we are storing these .properties files in aws codecommit, but we should store it somewhere else. Can you please suugest where we can store these

Comment: I am deploying into EC2 instance using Codedeploy

Comment: its does not depend on CI/CD tool, all you need to create and consume in your application. if you are in java you can check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/code-catalog-java-example_code-secretsmanager.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to deal with a secret in case of AWS, but one thing is clear it depends on the service where you will use and consume these secret.

But you explore these two

- The simplest way is to use the Environment variable.
- AWS Secrets Manager
- s3 ( for keeping files)

One common approach is to pass your secret as an environment variables, but in case of AWS I will recommend to go with [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-secrets-manager-store-distribute-and-rotate-credentials-securely/)

> AWS Secrets Manager is an AWS service that makes it easier for you to
>   manage secrets. Secrets can be database credentials, passwords,
>   third-party API keys, and even arbitrary text. You can store and
>   control access to these secrets centrally by using the Secrets Manager
>   console, the Secrets Manager command line interface (CLI), or the
>   Secrets Manager API and SDKs.

**Basic Secrets Manager Scenario**

> The following diagram illustrates the most basic scenario. It shows
>   how you can store credentials for a database in Secrets Manager, and
>   then use those credentials in an application that needs to access the
>   database.
>   [image]

**Compliance with Standards**

AWS Secrets Manager has undergone auditing for the [these](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html) standards and can be part of your solution when you need to obtain compliance certification.

You can explore this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/tutorials_basic.html) to read and write secret.

If you need to maintain files, not only object then you can store in s3 and pull files during deployment. but better to enable [server-side encprtion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingServerSideEncryption.html).

But I will prefer secret manager instead of s3 and environment variable.

You can for s3 [here](https://dev.to/joaquimadraz/envt---environment-variables-management-from-s3-dl3) and [here](https://github.com/sachaos/s3env)

Answer (score 0):

Bajjuri,

As Adil said in answer,

- AWS Secret Manager -- if you want to store data as key, value pairs.
- AWS S3 -- if you want to store files securely.

> Adding to his answer, you can use AWS [CodeDeploy Environment
>   Variables](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-codedeploy-environment-variables/) to fetch the files according to the your environment.
>   Let's say you've CodeDeploy deployment group for dev environment with
>   name "DEV" and deployment group for prod environment with name "PROD",
>   you can use this variable in bash script and call it in life cycle
>   hooks of appspec file to fetch the files or secret accordingly.

I've been using this technique in production for long and it works like a charm.